# TYPO3 Reconnect to database

Tags: php, mysql, typo3

I have a quite long running command controller/scheduler job, accessing the database at the very end.  With standard MySQL timeout settings it runs into a "MySQL Server has gone away".  Increasing the timeout I can circumvent the error.  However, I'd like to fix the problem.  How can I reconnect to the db (TYPO3 7.6)?

I tried

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->connectDB();
```

but this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection times out the state in TYPO3's `DatabaseConnection::$isConnected` is still set. You could try the following:

```
// isConnected() sends a ping and modifies internal $isConnected property
if (!$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->isConnected()) {
  // re-connect to database if required
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->connectDB();
}
```